# Django get ForeignKey field values from serializer in template

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a page form where the form is actually a DRF serializer (although I don't think this actually makes much difference).

I need to be able to access field values from the far end of the ForeignKey field **before** the object has been created.

```
*** Models.py ***
class Tag(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  colour = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Entry(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  date = models.DateField()
  tags = models.ForeignKey(Tag)

*** Serializer.py ***
class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Entry
        fields = '__all__'

*** views.py ***
from rest_framework.views import APIView
class Submit(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'submit.html'

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        context = {}
        context['serializer'] = serializers.EntrySerializer(context={'request': request})
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        ...
```

The following works fine for accessing 2 of the object fields:

```
*** submit.html ***
  {% for tag in serializer.tag.iter_options %}
    {{ tag.value }}-{{ tag.display_text }}
  {% endfor %}
```

However, I would like to do also be able to access the colour field:

```
*** submit.html ***
  {% for tag in serializer.tag.iter_options %}
    {{ tag.value }}-{{ tag.colour }}
  {% endfor %}
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

By digging into the original field model, the queryset can be obtained and iterated over:

```
{% for tag in serializer.tag.queryset.all %}
   {{ tag.value }}-{{ tag.colour }}
{% endfor %}
```